# 400 Error with JSON and HTTP POST

Tags: android, json, http-post, httpclient

Im trying to send an JSONObject over HTTPPost, however now Im receiving a 400 error.

I've been going through with the server coder, and making smaller and more concise calls with a less complicated JSON object, however I still receive the same 400 error.

How do I go about fixing it?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

    private Button loginButton;
    private TextView resultText;
    private EditText usernameText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private EditText switchChoice;
    private EditText installText;
    private int i;
    private String accessURL = "URL";
    private String accessNEW = "";
    public final String CONSUMER_KEY = "KEY";
    public final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "SECRET";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create the screen + pull back the saved instance state
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

        // initialize the buttons and text view for usability in the later codes
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);
        usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        installText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_install);
        switchChoice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_switch);



        // create the onclick listener for the login button to start the code to
        // login
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // pull data from EditText Boxes and create the JSON object
                    // to send information HTTP
                    String text = switchChoice.getText().toString();
                    i = Integer.parseInt(text);
                    JSONObject jOb = toJSON();
                    Log.d("JSONObjectCreation", jOb.toString());
                    // method to go through
                    processURL(jOb);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject();
        try {
            credentials.put("ConsumerSecret", CONSUMER_SECRET);
            credentials.put("ConsumerKey", CONSUMER_KEY);
            credentials.put("Password", "Sh0wT1me");
            credentials.put("Username", "sjones");

        } finally {
        }
        return credentials;
    }

    /*
     * Subclass that executes the connection and authentication to the server
     * using HTTPPost - Uses AsyncTask to execute the network connection on a
     * different thread
     * 
     * PARAMS: JSONObject -> input
     */
    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, String> {
        // Dialog box to let user know that it is processing
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);

        // Before the execution of the background task, this is executed in the
        // main thread
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Logging In...");

            // forces the dialog to show in the main thread
            Dialog.show();
        }

        // done in background thread, so that the main thread is not jammed up
        // preventing user interface usage
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... jObj) {
            int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; // create timeout time of 10 seconds
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

            // create a new httpClient with the httpParams of timeout time
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            String responseBody = null;
            try {

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(accessURL); 

                switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jObj.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
                    Log.d("request_entity", request.getEntity().getContent().toString());
                case 2:
                     StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{credentials"+jObj.toString()+"}");
                        Log.i("String_Entity", params.toString());

                     request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                     request.setEntity(params);
                case 3:
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{credentials" + jObj.toString()+"}");  
                    Log.i("String_Entity", se.toString());
                    se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    request.setEntity(se);
                case 4:

                }

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                /*
                  switch (status) {
                    case 200:

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {
                         responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    }
                    break;
                case 500:
                    responseBody = "500" + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
                    break;
                }
                */
                String statusS = Integer.toString(status);
                Log.d("request_status", statusS);
                return statusS + " " +response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
                //return responseBody;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            resultText.setText(result);
            Dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value updated",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void processURL(JSONObject thing) {
        // execute connection on new thread
        new PostTask().execute(thing);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
The switch part for setting the entity is there because I wasnt sure if the error is from the manner in which I was setting the entity, so after research, I created a switch to let me go through the different methods that the JSONObject can be encoded to the entity.

EDIT:
This came up in my logcat today:

```
07-19 11:13:27.812: W/ThrottleService(91): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91): problem reading network stats
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     ... 10 more
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-19 11:15:18.862: A/NetworkStats(91):     ... 13 more
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Your `accessURL`, is it ever set to the URL you are requesting a response from? I only saw `accessURL = "URL";`

Comment: there is an actual url, but Im not allowed to release it to the public.

Comment: Thought so, just checking. You might check this site for reference: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

Comment: Already did... Couldn't find the solution there :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized after some time the error came from the jObj variable in the doInBackground method.
I'm going to try to describe the error to the best of my abilities, and from what I have seen:
        protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... jObj) 
 The JSONObject variable isn't actually a JSONObject because of the '...', so when I used `jObj.toString()` it returned some weird sort of non-JSONObject looking string, almost like it wasn't encoded. I would go back and past the string here, however I've already changed my code so much that I dont want to risk losing it.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to your PostTask class.  I don't think you can pass accessURL into the class like that as a global variable.

Try something like:

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, String> {

    String accessURL;

    public PostTask(Context c, String accessURL) {
        this.accessURL = accessURL;
    }

}
```

Then in your processURL method do:

```
new PostTask(this, accessURL).execute(thing);
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I don't think OP will need to do that. accessURL should be visible in the AsyncTask already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at the whole JSON thing, but should

`StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{credentials" + jObj.toString()+"}");`

say

`StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{credentials: " + jObj.toString()+"}");`

?

edit: and maybe quotes around the word credentials. Again, I'm not good at JSON!

Comment: I realized that after I posted this, so I changed it in my code and it still didnt work...

Comment: ""s are not meant to be around the word credentials. I checked the api for an example.